# get full country name from country abbreviations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an array of countries names **abbreviated** am trying to get and display the full country's name in an object.

```
const countries = [
 {
   name:'Argentina',
   border:["NGA", "PAK","CHN"],
 },
 {
   name:'China',
   border:["ARG", "PAK"],
 },
 {
   name:'Nigeria',
   border:['PAK', 'CHN'],
 },
 {
   name:'Pakistan',
   border:['NGA', 'ARG'],
 },
]
```

so if i access the first index of the array which the name is Argentina and border of nga, pak and chn

```
const country = countries.find((con) => con.name === "Argentina");
console.log(country.border);
});
```

so am only seeing Abbr values in the console just as expected which is this

```
[NGA, PAK, CHN]
```

but I actually want something like this

```
[Nigeria, Pakistan, China]
```

**So how do I actually log country's fullName to the console with the objects provided because have thought and thought of a way to do it, but am just not getting the idea**  [data-URL-link](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all)

Comment: I would suggest using a refrence object to turn abbr vals into the full name.

Comment: am getting the data from an endpoint and this is how the data was structured. I only extracted some parts. I don't understand what your saying though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a `dict` as

```js
fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const dict = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc[curr.alpha3Code] = curr.name;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    console.log(dict);
  });
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```js
const dict = {
  NGA: "Nigeria",
  PAK: "Pakistan",
  CHN: "China",
  ARG: "Argentina",
};

const countries = [
  {
    name: "Argentina",
    border: ["NGA", "PAK", "CHN"],
  },
  {
    name: "China",
    border: ["ARG", "PAK"],
  },
  {
    name: "Nigeria",
    border: ["PAK", "CHN"],
  },
  {
    name: "Pakistan",
    border: ["NGA", "ARG"],
  },
];

const result = countries.map((o) => dict[o.border[0]]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the data am getting is the list of all countries in the whole universe, I only extracted this from the data as an example. assigning object values manually won't work.

Comment: You're fast  cool to see how similar our code is and how close in time we responded. I hope that's a point to the quality of my response. I like your description of the object as a dictionary.

Comment: without `lookup`, You can't do this.

Comment: @HR01M8055 I updated the Post with the Link am getting my data from

Comment: I've udpated the code to make the `dict` from API

Comment: again, I had just finished writing the fetch and reduce as you posted it  good stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can map the results by a function which changes abbrs into full names.

```js
const countries = [
 {
   name:'Argentina',
   border:["NGA", "PAK","CHN"],
 },
 {
   name:'China',
   border:["ARG", "PAK"],
 },
 {
   name:'Nigeria',
   border:['PAK', 'CHN'],
 },
 {
   name:'Pakistan',
   border:['NGA', 'ARG'],
 },
]

const abrRefrence = {
  CHN: "China",
  PAK: "Pakistan",
  NGA: "Nigeria",
  ARG: "Argentina",
}

const abrToFull = abr => abrRefrence[abr];

const country = countries.find(con => con.name === "Argentina");
console.log(country.border.map(abrToFull));
```

Comment: Am getting like the whole country in the universe, I only extracted these values as an example. the idea of assigning the Abbr values to their full names might not be possible

Comment: You should construct an object for the relationship between abr and country in the whole universe. Another option is to build logic to see the strength of a match between abrs and country names, but probably not needed for your app. You could make a list of all fulls and all abrs easily, but the problem is an abr will not always be the first 3 chars of the full.